# Py-Polars DateTime Conversion

Tags: python, datetime, python-polars

I am currently exploring Py-Polars and are having some difficulties with getting the Date32 format in its dataframe. I have tried the following means:

1. Conversion from Pandas to PyPolars directly

```
import pandas as pd
import pypolars as pyp

a = pd.read_csv(*CSV File*)
b = pyp.from_pandas(a)
```

The error code is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    pyp.from_pandas(a)
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pypolars\functions.py", line 235, in from_pandas
    pl_s = Series(k, s, nullable=True).cast(datatypes.Date64)
  File "C:\Users\*Username*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pypolars\series.py", line 783, in cast
    return wrap_s(f())
RuntimeError: Any(ArrowError(ComputeError("Casting from Int32 to Date64 not supported")))
```

2. Conversion DateTime to String in Pandas, convert to PyPolars, converting String to DateTime in PyPolars

```
def changeDateTime(value):
    return str(value)

a["ACTUAL_DROP_DATE"] = a["ACTUAL_DROP_DATE"].apply(changeDateTime)
a["ACTUAL_END_DATE"] = a["ACTUAL_END_DATE"].apply(changeDateTime)

b = pyp.from_pandas(a)

def changeStrBack(value):
    if value == np.str("NaT"):
        return ""
    else:
        year = int(value[0:4])
        month = int(value[5:7])
        day = int(value[8:10])
        return pyp.datetime(year, month, day)

b["ACTUAL_DROP_DATE"] = b["ACTUAL_DROP_DATE"].apply(changeStrBack, dtype_out = pyp.Date32)
b["ACTUAL_END_DATE"] = b["ACTUAL_END_DATE"].apply(changeStrBack, dtype_out = pyp.Date32)
```

This has thrown me all the null values upon conversion. (i.e. both columns are completely null).

Hope anyone have some ideas on how I can get the columns to datetime in PyPolars.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please show the first lines of your pandas df `a`? Would be necessary to fix the error that happens in the first step.

Comment: Is your function not designed for a single value?
Yet you are passing a series from the apply.
Perhaps you need `apply(lambda x: changeStrBack(x)`?

In any case the error points to the `dtype_out` kwarg not being in the supported format

Comment: vote to close since OP didn't ever give the first few lines and this is over a year old.  @FObersteiner, are you going for an edit badge with this ancient question edit?